# PHP Symfony EasyAdmin - configure actions - cant find field choice

Tags: php, symfony4, easyadmin

I dont know where i can find place to change field from list to checkbox.
I want to change form in EasyAdmin, in my field i have:

```
<div class="form-group  field-entity">
```

and i want to change it to:

```
<div class="form-group  field-choice">
```

I looked for in source code but i cant find the place where is it.
In easy_admin.yaml i have only label of my form and i don't have details of this settings :/

edit:

in templates/bundles/ i dont have directory like: EasyAdminBundle
in src/Controller/EasyAdmin i have only CatalogListUserController.php - backend code

EDIT:
in:
/src/Controller/EasyAdmin/CatalogListUserController.php
i have:

```
namespace App\Controller\EasyAdmin;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\EasyAdminController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\EasyAdminEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Entity\{Report, CatalogList, CatalogListUser};
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class CatalogListUserController extends EasyAdminController
{
    // public function createNewFormBuilder($entity, $view)
    public function createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view)
    {
        $id = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $conn = $em->getConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT id, `name` FROM `catalog_list` WHERE user_id = $id AND status = 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $choices = [];
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $choices[$row['name']] = $row['id'];
        }
        
        $ids = [];
        if ($view === 'edit') {
            $selected = $entity->getUser()->getListUsers();
            foreach ($selected as $s){
                $ids[] = $s->getId();
            }
        }

        $formBuilder = parent::createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view);
        
        // Listy - checkbox
        $formBuilder->add('catalogLists', ChoiceType::class, [
            'required' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'label' => 'Listy',
            'choices' => $choices, 
            'data' => $ids,          
        ]);

    // User - change list of users but we dont create user list here - and we cant set here list or checkbox
        $fields = $formBuilder->all();
        foreach ($fields as $fieldId => $field) {
            if ($fieldId == 'user') {
                $options = [
                    'class' => 'App\Entity\User',
                ];
                $options['query_builder'] = function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('e');
        
                    return $qb->where($qb->expr()->eq('e.company', ':company'))
                        ->setParameter('company', $this->getUser()->getCompany())
                        ->orderBy('e.firstname', 'DESC');
                };
                $formBuilder->add($fieldId, EntityType::class, $options);
            } 
        }
           

        return $formBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * The method that is executed when the user performs a 'new' action on an entity.
     *
     * @return Response|RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function newAction()
    {
        $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::PRE_NEW);

        $entity = $this->executeDynamicMethod('createNew<EntityName>Entity');

        $easyadmin = $this->request->attributes->get('easyadmin');
        $easyadmin['item'] = $entity;
        $this->request->attributes->set('easyadmin', $easyadmin);

        $fields = $this->entity['new']['fields'];

        $newForm = $this->executeDynamicMethod('create<EntityName>NewForm', [$entity, $fields]);

        $newForm->handleRequest($this->request);
        if ($newForm->isSubmitted() && $newForm->isValid()) {
            foreach ($entity->catalogLists as $id) {
                // check if already exists
                $catalogList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CatalogList::class)->find($id);
                $catalogListUser = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CatalogListUser::class)->findOneBy(['user' => $entity->getUser(), 'list' => $catalogList, 'status' => 1]);
                // add to database
                if (!$catalogListUser) {
                    $newEntity = clone $entity;
                    $newEntity->setList($catalogList);
                    $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::PRE_PERSIST, ['entity' => $newEntity]);
                    $this->executeDynamicMethod('persist<EntityName>Entity', [$newEntity, $newForm]);
                    $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::POST_PERSIST, ['entity' => $newEntity]); 
                }
            }

            return $this->redirectToReferrer();
        }

        $this->dispatch(EasyAdminEvents::POST_NEW, [
            'entity_fields' => $fields,
            'form' => $newForm,
            'entity' => $entity,
        ]);

        $parameters = [
            'form' => $newForm->createView(),
            'entity_fields' => $fields,
            'entity' => $entity,
        ];

        return $this->executeDynamicMethod('render<EntityName>Template', ['new', $this->entity['templates']['new'], $parameters]);
    }

    protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
    {

        $response =  parent::createListQueryBuilder('CatalogListUser, User', $sortDirection, $sortField, $dqlFilter); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        $response->join('entity.user','user');
        $response->andWhere('user.company = :company')->andWhere('entity.status = 1')->setParameter('company', $this->getUser()->getCompany());

        return $response;
    }
}
```

and my form is:
[image]
so i want at Users change from list to checkbox. As you see in my code line:

```
foreach ($fields as $fieldId => $field) {
```

only change my content of this list but when i comment thos block i still have list here - so this list is generated in another place - i cant find it, this is problem :/

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields on Easyadmin are configured from the CRUD controller `configureFields()` method. If your crud controller is CatalogListUserController (if you have created it from console it is maybe located at `src/Controller/Admin/CatalogListUserCrudController.php`) you could do something like this:

```
class CatalogListUserController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    //...

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            // other fields...
            
            ChoiceField::new('your_field_name')
                ->setChoices([
                    'Choice 1' => 'value1',
                    'Choice 2' => 'value2',
                    // ...
                ])                
            // other fields...
        ];
    }
```

Refer to this doc to configure fields and its behaviour: https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields.html

Comment: thanks, i edited and added more info about problem

Comment: Which versions of Symfony and Easyadmin are you using?

Comment: "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^2.1",
"symfony/asset": "4.4.*",

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with these outdated versions. I think it would be very useful if you edit/tag your question with this versions to find a correct answer. Anyway I'd try setting options for your field as this: `if ($fieldId == 'user') { $options = [ 'class' => 'App\Entity\User', 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true, ];` 
You'll need to ensure that CatalogListUser entity is able to handle multiple users. Let me know if it works to update the answer for future reference.

Comment: thank you, your comment resolve problem and i have checkbox list now. As you said, after change it my CatalogListUserController.php raise exception: $newForm->handleRequest($this->request); // after change from form list User (one) to form checkbox User(more then one) here is error: Expected argument of type "App\Entity\User or null", "instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given at property path "user".

Comment: Glad it helps. The error you mention is logical considering that you now need to store a collection of Users in the entity. The solution to that problem is beyond the scope of this question, but it shouldn't be difficult to solve by changing the type accordingly in the affected property.